# How to overcome implicit coercion? (Casting to custom class)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, casting

I have a class that extends the `Sprite` class (which makes it a `DisplayObject`), and I have added it as a child to `stage` for visualization: `stage.addChild(object)`.

I would like to make an alteration to this object by taking a reference to it out of the stage and work with it (`stage.getChildByName(object)`), but now the object I receive from the stage is of type `DisplayObject`. If I am sure this object received from the stage is of my class - can I cast the displayObject to my class somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is done 2 ways in AS3.

You could do a proper cast:

```
MyClass(object)
```

This will throw an error if the cast fails.

You could also use the `as` keyword:

```
object as MyClass;
```

This will return null if the cast fails.

---

You need to be aware, that `getChildByName` does not accept an object, but a string (that corresponds to the `.name` (or instance name) value of a display object.   If you already have a reference to `object`, then there is no need look it up from `stage.getChildByName`

Comment: I will test and accept if it works out - this seems to fit what I expected.

Comment: stupid question (follow up question), but I believe that I give my object a name (object.name = "hey") before adding it to the stage and then later tried getChildByName("hey") and it returns null. It should be possible to access it like this, no?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - post the actual code your using to your question and I'll look at it.

Comment: note that for the first form (`MyClass(object)`) will actually *create/convert* a new object for certain base types (e.g. `String`, `XML`)